# if content == smth in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

sorry if the title of the question not clear , really I can not describe it with words !

I use Fancy Music Player : http://codecanyon.net/item/fancy-music-player-v20-jquery-plugin
so I can not edit the main plugin file , so I have to do it with this way !

I have two lists with same contents :

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li><em> item one  </em>  <a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></li>
    <li><em> item two  </em>  <a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></li>
    <li><em> item three  </em>  <a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2">
    <em> item one  </em>
    <em> item two  </em>
    <em> item three  </em>
</ul>
```

I can delete item in the first list ..
but I want to delete the item in the #list2 too if it has the same text
unforsantly I can not use id , so I want a way to do something like this :

```
    $(".delete").live('click',function(eve) {
      eve.preventDefault();
      // 1- delete item here in the first list 
      //    it's ok

      // 2- delete the same item in the second list  ('#list2') using text inside <em> ?
       var titleItem = $(this).parent().find('em').text(); // i get here ( item one or item two .. etc .  depends on the item clicked above )
       // here I want to see if this titleItem ==  ('#list2 em').text .. so delete it too
       // I have to use the conent here cuz I can not edit to the main jquery plugin :(

    });
```

thanks ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try -

```
 $(".delete").live('click',function(eve) {
     eve.preventDefault();
     var titleItem = $(this).parent().find('em').text();
     $(this).parent().find('em').remove();
     $("#list2").find("em:contains('" + titleItem + "')").remove();
 });
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/pJmTF/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".delete").live('click',function(event) {

    var titleItem = $(this).parent().find('em').text().trim(); 

    $("#list2 li").each(function(i, item){
        $item = $(item);
        if($item.find('em').text().trim() === titleItem){
             $item.remove();   
        }
    });

});
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aCE4z/)

Answer (score 1):

Here: check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/5KL36/).

You would need to save the text to a variable, then search for it in list2 with a .each() function.

```
$(".delete").live('click',function() {
    var t = $(this).parent().find('em').text();
      // 1- delete item here in the first list 
    $(this).parent().remove();
      // 2- delete the same item in the second list  ('#list2') using text inside <em> ?
    $('#list2 em').each(function(){
        if($(this).text()==t) $(this).remove(); 
    });
          event.preventDefault();
    });
```